# How to access QML TableView selection property from python using PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I would like to get a Python representation of a QML TableView selection, using PyQt5. I haven't found an easy solution yet.

Assuming this example files:

**main_window.qml**

```py
ApplicationWindow {
    // ...

    signal selectionChanged()

    property alias tableSelection: tableView.selection

    TableView{
        id: tableView

        model: []

        selectionMode: SelectionMode.ContiguousSelection
        selection.onSelectionChanged: selectionChanged()
    }
}
```

**main_window.py**

```py
class MainWindowView:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
        self.__engine.load("main_window.qml")

    def __get_root_window(self) -> QWindow:
        return self.__engine.rootObjects()[0]

    def __get_property(self, property_name: str):
        return self.__get_root_window().property(property_name)

    def get_table_selection(self):
        return self.__get_property("tableSelection")
```

`get_table_selection()` returns a QObject, which is not what I want.

If possible, I would like to access table selection as a Python list of (selected) indices. Is this possible? If yes, what is the best way to achieve it?

Thank you in advance for any help.